# Multilayer Neuronal Network Perceptron; FileWriter is not working, Output does not work properly

Tags: csv, machine-learning, weka, perceptron

I tried to build up a machine learning model in Java with Weka.
Here is my code:

```java
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import weka.classifiers.Evaluation;
import weka.classifiers.functions.MultilayerPerceptron;
import weka.classifiers.evaluation.Prediction;
import weka.core.Instances;
import weka.core.converters.ConverterUtils.DataSource;

public class multiLayerExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String filename = "../train.arff";
        DataSource source = new DataSource(filename);
        Instances train = source.getDataSet();
        int cid1 = train.numAttributes() - 1;
        train.setClassIndex(cid1);
        
        Instances validation = DataSource.read(".../validation.arff");
        int cid2 = validation.numAttributes() - 1;
        validation.setClassIndex(cid2);

        Instances test = DataSource.read("../test1.arff");
        int cid3 = test.numAttributes() - 1;
        test.setClassIndex(cid3);

        MultilayerPerceptron tree = new MultilayerPerceptron();
        tree.buildClassifier(train);

        Evaluation eval = new Evaluation(train);
        eval.evaluateModel(tree, validation);
        System.out.println(eval.toSummaryString("\nResults_RF\n\n", false));
    //  System.out.println(eval.toClassDetailsString());
    //  System.out.println(eval.toMatrixString());

        ArrayList<Prediction> al = eval.predictions();
        ArrayList<String[]> as = new ArrayList<String[]>(al.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++) {
            String[] s = new String[1];
            s[0] = al.get(i).toString();
            s[0] = s[0].substring(9, 11);
            as.add(s);
            System.out.println(s);
        }
        ArrayList<String[]> li = new ArrayList<String[]>(al.size());
        li.addAll(as);
         
        System.out.println(li.addAll(as));
//      String csv = "../output.csv";
//      CSVSaver writer = new CSVSaver(new FileWriter(csv));
//
//      writer.writeAll(li);
//      writer.close();
//      
        //Storing again in csv
        BufferedWriter writer1 = new BufferedWriter(
        new FileWriter("../output.csv"));
        System.out.print(li);
        writer1.write(li.toString());
        writer1.newLine();
        writer1.flush();
        writer1.close();
    }
}
```

The problems I have are:
CSVSaver writer = new CSVSaver(new FileWriter(csv));
The following error message occurs: "CSVSaver cannot be resolved to a type"
And if I comment it out and use the method inserted below it (//Storing again in csv), it inserts the following data in the output csv:
"[[Ljava.lang.String;@53f65459, [Ljava.lang.String;@3b088d51, [Ljava.lang.String;@1786dec2,..."

What can I do, to make it work?
Thanks for your help in advance!

I tried to write a new CSV Saver (see: //Storing again in csv) but the output is not readable.
I expect the predictions to be written to the output file. The format is all numbers (double).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weka's [CSVSaver](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/core/converters/CSVSaver.html) is for storing [weka.core.Instances](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/core/Instances.html) objects in CSV files, not just any lists.

Also, Java arrays are objects but lack a custom `toString()` method. Instead, you will see things like `[Ljava.lang.String;@3b088d51`, which consists of the type signature and the object ID (see [JNI type signatures](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/jni/types.html#type-signatures)).

Based on your code, it looks like you are trying save the predicted values in a CSV file. But instead of turning predictions to strings and then extracting the relevant parts, you could just straight obtain the predicted value from the [Prediction](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/evaluation/Prediction.html) object (concrete implementation for numeric classes is [NumericPrediction](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/evaluation/NumericPrediction.html) and [NominalPrediction](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/evaluation/NominalPrediction.html) for nominal classes).

I would rewrite your code for generating the CSV file with the predictions as follows:

```java
FileWriter fwriter1 = new FileWriter("../output.csv");
BufferedWriter writer1 = new BufferedWriter(fwriter1);
for (Prediction p: eval.predictions()) {
  writer1.write("" + p.predicted());
  writer1.newLine();
}
writer1.flush();
writer1.close();
fwriter1.close();
```

If your class should be nominal, `.predicted()` will return the label index. This index you can cast to `int` and retrieve the label from your class attribute:

```java
String label = train.classAttribute().value((int) p.predicted());
```

**NB:** You should always make sure that your train, validation and test set are compatible to avoid strange behavior from your classifier, using the [equalHeadersMsg](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/core/Instances.html#equalHeadersMsg-weka.core.Instances-) method:

```java
String msg;
msg = train.equalHeadersMsg(test);
if (msg != null)
  throw new IllegalStateException("Train/test not compatible:\n" + msg);
msg = train.equalHeadersMsg(validation);
if (msg != null)
  throw new IllegalStateException("Train/validation not compatible:\n" + msg);
```

Comment: Great! Then please flag my answer as the accepted one.